# Ubuntu cannot boot after crash

Tags: boot, 18.04, dell

I was running some code when my computer, Dell XPS 13 97 froze, probably due to lack of RAM. I performed a hard shutdown but now when I restart, I get this screen:

[image: boot screen]

I've looked around all day but all the commands that other answers suggests don't work for some reason. Dell's support assistant did fix the issue, and when I try to reset the OS factory state it says "unable to find a medium containing a live file system".

I also tried using a USB to try to fix it but I cannot see my local hard drive. The hard drive is there though, since I can see it from the BIOS (it's listed as one of the boot options).

I really don't know enough Ubuntu to solve it on my own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the `initramfs` prompt, type `fsck -f /`. Repeat if there are errors. Once done, type `exit` and reboot the computer.

If that doesn't work for you, we'll do it the old fashioned way...

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- open a `terminal` window
- type `sudo fdisk -l`
- identify the /dev/XXXX device name for your "Linux Filesystem"
- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/XXXX` # replacing XXXX with the number you found earlier
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors
- type `reboot`

**Update #1:**

Turned out that the BIOS had reset the SATA controller to RAID. (thanks @GabrielaGarcia). We reset it back to AHCI, did a `fsck` to verify proper disk operation, and the system is working again.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Neither of those worked though. From the `initramfs` prompt I get that the directory `/` does not exist. When I type `sudo fdisk -l` from the usb live terminal the only /dev/sda shown is the usb stick itself. For some reason, ubuntu can't see the drives.

Comment: @MiltonLlera that's not good. Is this a desktop machine? Try booting to the Ubuntu Live and start `gparted` and see if it can find something beyond the USB stick. Use the drive selection box to see other drives... if they are seen. Also try the `lsblk` command. What "code" were you running when it failed? Report back.

Comment: It's my laptop, and no gparted cannot find anything. I can see the ssd from BIOS, just not from Ubuntu.

Comment: The  drive itself doesn't show up in GParted? Or it does but without  partitions? In the first case you should check SATA settings as the hard shutdown may have changed to an unsupported mode like RAID. In the second case the partitions are corrupt. Either way, not good.

Comment: `lsblk` returns a list of loop0 to loop7 plus the sda for the usb stick. The code I was running was a simulation using differential equations. It was supposed to be very simple, a toy example, but I changed the solver and it seems to have incresaed memory usage to 100%. Also, in one of the restarts I manage to get a message regarding my CPU being throttled due to overheating.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia yes, SATA operation has changed to RAID On.

Comment: Do you have Windows on this machine? If so, does it boot? If not, then reset your BIOS to factory or default specs, then check the SATA setting and see if its changed from RAID. Also, assure that the BIOS can/cannot see the drive now. Report back.

Comment: No, only Ubuntu (it's a Developer Edition XPS). I reseted the BIOS to default settings and it stays in RAID mode. I can still see the ssd in the boot sequence menu.

Comment: Flip the SATA controller to AHCI or SATA (depending on what your choices are) and lets see what happens. Report back.

Comment: It worked!!! Anything else I need to check to make sure there are no issues?

Comment: Great news! Which one did you end up choosing? Yes, run the `fsck` asap. After you reply, I'll update my answer, and maybe you can accept it if it was helpful.

Comment: @heynnema yes sure, once you edit the answer I'll accept it. I ended up choosing AHCI. When running fsck, should I do it from the usb stick? As I understand it, I should not do it from the actual OS with the drive mounted.

Comment: Yes, run `fsck` from the USB stick. You cannot `fsck` with the drive mounted... as when you are booted to it. My last answer edit will take just seconds :-)

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Do you know exactly what could have happened?

Comment: No, it's very bizarre. Glad it's working for you. Thanks for the accept!

Comment: No problem, much appreciate the help. `fsck` returned no errors, so apparently the whole issue was that it went to RAID mode. cheers!!